# Impulse Response of a series RC filter where the output voltage is taken across the Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, resistors, filter

I am finding it difficult to understand the steps to derive the impulse response of a series RC filter where the output voltage is taken across the capacitor, the equation to derive is:

h(t)= (1/RC) e^(-t/RC)

Comment: You will need to solve this as a differential equation.  Is this a homework question?  Hints are that the current in the capacitor is equal to the instantaneous change in voltage (I = dV/dt)

Comment: Its not a homework question, more like explanation in the lecture slides in which the steps do not make sense.

Comment: Would be better if you could include what the slide content was and which part you didn't understand.  My answer below is one of many ways to look at the situation...

Answer (score 1):

Take the equations of the relationship between voltage and current in a resister and capacitor

```
Ic = C dVc/dt     (1)
Ir = 1/R Vr         (2)
```

They are in series which indicates 2 things:

1. The current in the resistor is the same as the capacitor (assuming no load on the output).
2. The total Input voltage is the sum of the two.

Giving these equations:

```
Ic = Ir            (3)
Vi = Vc + Vr       (4)
```

putting (1) & (2) into (3), use (4) to replace Vr

```
1/R Vr = C dVc/dt
1/RC (Vi - Vc) = dVc/dt    (5)
```

Before this can be integrated, the Vc must be with dVc.  Rearrange equation (5), and then integrate (assume `Vi` is constant and does not change with time)

```
1/RC dt = 1/(Vi-Vc) dVc

1/RC t = -ln(Vi-Vc) + K
```

Before `time 0` Vi was stable for an limitless amount of time, `Vc` will match `Vi` as an initial condition; in this case 0V.  We evaluate the integral from time `t0` and `Vc=V0`, to time `t` and output `Vo`.  (`Vo` is equal to Vc, and now is a good time to make that swap)

```
(1/RC) t |t=0->t = -ln(Vi-Vo) |Vc=0->Vo
(1/RC) t = -ln(Vi-Vo) -  -ln(Vi-V0) = -ln( (Vi-Vo)/(Vi-V0) )
```

A bit more rearranging

```
-t /RC = ln( (Vi-Vo)/(Vi-V0) )
exp(-t / RC) = (Vi-Vo)/(Vi-V0)            (6)
```

if `V0` is 0 then:

```
exp(-t / RC) = 1 - Vo/Vi
Vo/Vi = 1 - exp(-t (R/C))
```

The step response is:

```
Vo = Vi( 1 - exp(-t / RC) )                    (7a)
```

But you asked for the impulse response.  It might not be obvious, but I need to keep `V0` in equation (6) to show what the impulse response is.

```
Vo = (V0-Vi) exp(-t / RC) + Vi                   (7b)
```

What if the system gets a pulse of infinite magnitude for a duration of `0` seconds.  A very theoretical question, as a pulse can not be `0` seconds long and infinity is not a value.  So we use a limit to see what equation (7a) equals when `t->0` and `Vi->1/t` (The units of the '1' are Volt-seconds, such that no matter the duration the pules integrates to 1Vs, a unit pulse).

```
Lim t->0 of Vp = (1/t) ( 1 - exp(-t/RC) )                  (8)
Lim t->0 of Vp = (1/1) ( 0 - exp(-t/RC)*(-1/RC) )          (9)
Lim t->0 of Vp = 1/RC                                      (10)
```

Equation (8) results in a 'zero over zero' situation (exp(...) on top and 't' on bottom), which means that the limit of the quotient of the derivative of the 2 will equal the same value (derivative of top and bottom, and re-evaluate the limit); equation (9).  Equation (9) can be directly evaluated with `t=0, giving equation (10).  So immediately after the impulse (after... which is still at time zero), the Output voltage is suddenly at 1/RC. (who ever heard of a capacitor changing voltage in an instant! but remember this is theoretical with the 'impossible' impulse).

Bring back equation (7b).  The initial output `V0` is 1/RC; the input `Vi` is zero (back to zero after that momentary lapse of reality that got the output suddenly to 1/RC!).  The result is a mathematical equation representing what would happen if an impulse function hit.

```
Vo = 1/RC exp(-t / RC)
```